# Most efficient way to check if database contains any row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, where-clause

I have an application that polls a database every 60 second with the following query;

```
 SELECT TOP (1) id FROM item WHERE status = 5
```

I am wondering if there are any more efficient way to check if my table contains any rows at all? I don't need the return value here, I just need to check if the table contains any row with that status.

Comment: Using `top` without `order by` is a bit odd and the whole issue is best avoided by using `exists` as in GMB's answer. Is there an index on `status`?

Comment: No there is no index I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `exists`:

```
select case when exists (select 1 from item where status = 5) 
    then 1 
    else 0 
end as has_status_5
```

Comment: Tried this and it seems to work though it wasn't that much faster. Execution time with my query was 00:00:00.044. With this one 00:00:00.041.